# Get last value and this years value to compare

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table on sql server 2014 with date, value, type and project columns, i want to write a query that returns last value from past year and latest value from current year, but if the current year but if there is no entry in this year it returns empty in one row.
My table :

```
Id |    date          |   value   | type |    project   
1  | 2019-01-01 |      1       |   a    | p1
2  | 2018-01-01 |      1       |   a    | p1
3  | 2018-01-01 |      1       |   b    | p1
```

Result i expected :

```
CurrentyearDate  |  currentyearvalue   |   pastdate | pastvalue  | type | project

2019-01-01  | 1 |      2018-01-01       |   1  | a | p1   
Null  | null |      2018-01-01       |   1  | b | p1
```

I've used ROW_NUMBER and partition method but can't make it though

Comment: which dbms (mysql, postgresql, tsql / mssql, oracle) you are using? please tag your question.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Sql server 2014

Comment: You can use `LEAD` or `LAG` with `OVER()` to get the previous/next value in a partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try outer self join along with `DATEPART`:

```
select t1.date as  CurrentyearDate, t1.value as currentyearvalue,
t2.date as  pastdate, t2.pastvalue as currentyearvalue ,t2.type ,t2.project   
from <<tableName>> t1 right join <<tableName>> t2
on DATEPART(MONTH, t1.lastUpdateTime)=DATEPART(MONTH, t2.lastUpdateTime)
and DATEPART(dd, t1.lastUpdateTime)=DATEPART(dd, t2.lastUpdateTime)
and DATEPART(year, t1.lastUpdateTime)=DATEPART(year, t2.lastUpdateTime)+1;
```

Comment: What is the output are you getting?